# Include a zipped module as a dependency to another project's pom.xml

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, pom.xml, talend

I have a project A, which is present in a zip file build through Talend. Inside the zip file, it looks like this :
Folder AA,
Folder lib,
jobinfo.properties

Inside the lib folder there are several jar files.
Inside Folder AA, there is the project A jar files.

Now I have another project B, which requires project A as a dependency. And project A requires dependencies which are present in that lib folder.

Now how do I import project A.zip into Project B , through pom.xml ?

Comment: Not without elbow grease.  Can you ask the owners to create maven artifacts instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual way would be to unpack the ZIP and either deploy the JARs to your company Nexus/Artifactory or install them in your local repository.

After that, you can reference them as normal dependencies.